# How do I know when a Stream (Node.js, MongoDB) is ready for changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to make sure that a `Stream` is ready for changes before I can send data to the client. My code:

```
// Get the Stream (MongoDB collection)
let stream = collection.watch()
// Generate identifier to send it to the client
const uuid = uuid()
// Listen for changes
stream
  .on('change', () => {
    // Send something to WebSocket client
    webSocket.emit('identifier', uuid)
  })

// Mutate data base collection to kick off the "change" event
await collection.updateOne()
```

The line with `webSocket.emit` is my problem. How do I know if the `Stream` is already ready to receive events? It happens that `change` event never occurs so the `webSocket.emit` gets never invoked.

### TL;DR

Basically, I need to send something to the client but need to make sure that the `Stream` is ready for receiving events before that.

Comment: Not sure if thats even possible. watch streams work across shards & clusters, and timing there is even more difficult.

Comment: `.watch` is synchronous. the `stream` is ready as soon as instantiated. `stream.on(..)` switches the `stream` to flowing mode as soon as the listeners is attached.  Are you sure it is a timing issue? The "event never occurs" suggests it doesn't work at all. Are change streams enabled on db side? Can you see any events if you `console.log` instead of `webSocket.emit` ?

Comment: Thanks @AlexBlex. It works like 80 % and no, when it doesn't work there is no log. I'm not sure if there is an essential difference between the MongoDB and the Node.js `Stream`.

Comment: Yeah, I could reproduce the error. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a race condition where your update query is executed before the changeStream aggregation pipeline reaches the server. Basically you need to wait for the stream cursor to be set before triggering the change.

I couldn't find any "cursor ready" event, so as a workaround you can check its id. It is assigned by the server so when it is available on the client it kinda guarantee that all consecutive data changes will be captured.

Something like this should do the job:

```
async function streamReady(stream) {
    return new Promise(ok => {
        const i = setInterval(() => {
            if (stream.cursor.cursorState.cursorId) {
                clearInterval(i);
                return ok()
            }
        }, 1)
    });
}
```

Then in your code:

```
// Get the Stream (MongoDB collection)
let stream = collection.watch()
// Generate identifier to send it to the client
const uuid = uuid()
// Listen for changes
stream
  .on('change', () => {
    // Send something to WebSocket client
    webSocket.emit('identifier', uuid)
  })

await streamReady(stream);    

// Mutate data base collection to kick off the "change" event
await collection.updateOne()
```

---

**Disclaimer:**

The streamReady function above relies on `cursorState`. It is an internal field which can be changed without notice even in a patch version update of the driver.

Comment: Thanks again, Alex! My other solution was also an interval but I was querying the collection on every iteration. Your solution is much better. However, it's quite dangerous. Do you think its sensible to request the MongoDB team to make `cursorState` as a public API?

Comment: But of course. I am sure they will appreciate the feedback. I wouldn't expect the change soon tho. The problem is quite specific to tailable cursors. It's the only case where you need low-level events like "cursor ready". Unfortunately cursor inherits EventEmitter only on higher level in node-mongodb-native whilst cursor initialization happens in parent core cursor in mongodb-core. To put it simply - it's hidden by design whatever reasons were. I personally would take the risk of using internal state and cover it with a test to ensure no regression on npm update.

Comment: If you are interested: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-2029 Thanks again for the support.

Comment: Good news, they are working on it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-2247

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this work without using an undocumented piece of the API.

```js
    await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      changeStream.once('resumeTokenChanged', () => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
```

I'm using the `resumeTokenChanged` event. This worked for me.